# Hibernate collection update foiled by unique index

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I'm trying to move a child object from one parent to another, in a database controlled by Hibernate.   I'm getting an error on a table created and controlled by Hibernate through the `@OneToMany` annotation.   Hopefully someone knows a way around this.

I have two objects, one containing a List of the other.   Let's call them Kennel and Dog.   What I'm doing is moving a `Dog` from one `Kennel` to another `Kennel`:

```
    Dog dog = dogService.getDog(dogId);
    Kennel oldKennel = dog.getKennel();

    if (oldKennel.getDogs().contains(dog)) {
        oldKennel.getDogs().remove(dog);
    }

    Kennel newKennel = kennelService.getKennel(newKennelId);
    newKennel.getDogs().add(dog);
    dog.setKennel(newKennel);
```

There are three tables involved:

```
-- Table is mapped to Kennel object    
TABLE kennels (kennel_id int)
-- Table is a join table controlled by Hibernate
TABLE kennels_dogs (kennels_kennel_id int, dogs_dog_id int)
-- Table is mapped to Dog object
TABLE dogs (dog_id int)
```

The specific error that I'm getting is on the join table `kennels_dogs`

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '14' for key 'dogs_dog_id'
```

But there's only one record in the file with that ID - the one I'm trying to update.  What Hibernate seems to be doing is trying to **INSERT** a record in the `kennels_dogs` table with the new values before it **DELETES** the old record.

For example, let's say a `Dog` with id=14 is in the `Kennel` with id=12.   We want to move the Dog to the Kennel with id=47.  Manually, you could do this with these commands:

```
DELETE FROM kennels_dogs WHERE kennels_kennel_id=12 AND dogs_dog_id=12
INSERT INTO kennels_dogs (kennels_kennel_id, dogs_dog_id) VALUES (47, 12)
```

What Hibernate does is perform these actions in the opposite order:

```
INSERT INTO kennels_dogs (kennels_kennel_id, dogs_dog_id) VALUES (47, 12)
DELETE FROM kennels_dogs WHERE kennels_kennel_id=12 AND dogs_dog_id=12
```

The `INSERT` fails because of the unique index on the field `dogs_dog_id` - there is already a record with `dogs_dog_id` = 12 in the table.

It seems like the obvious solution might be to delete the unique index, but without knowing why it's there, I'm hesitant to remove it (and logically, it's correct - a `Dog` can only be in one place at a time.)

Anyone have a brilliant way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems strange to me that you have a kennels_dogs join table. This should not be necessary for a @OneToMany. According to the Hibernate docs:

> 6.2.5. One-to-many associations
>
> A one-to-many association links the tables of two classes via a foreign key with no
>   intervening collection table.

I would make sure you have `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "dog")` annotated on the dog collection in your Kennel class, and `@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "kennel_id", nullable = false)`
annotated on your Dog class.

Comment: Yes, there's no good reason for that table to be there since this is a one-to-many relationship.   Lots of people worked on this design over several years, and I'm sure this is an artifact of an earlier age.

Comment: I'm marking this correct because it is in fact the proper answer - this schema should not have a join table in it.   However, the way I actually solved this was completely different, and was so stupid and idiosyncratic that hopefully no one else will ever need to solve this same problem.   It involved controller level transactions and a terrible screen design.  Like I said hopefully no one else will ever run into it.  :(